# Screencasts from quicktime are too large to share

Tags: screen-casting, quicktime, handbrake

I tend to take quite a lot of video screencasts to illustrate bugs and features to 3rd parties during web development projects.

To achieve this is I use Quicktime on my Mac and then go to "File > New screen recording", record the video and press "Stop". Then it asks me to save the video which I do, but it always comes out as a very large file, for instance a 30 second video depending on how much I scroll on the screen can be 50mb (not the best for sharing).

At the moment to get around this before I share the videos on email or in Trello (project management tool) I setup a queue in Handbrake and run all the videos through there in the 'normal setting'. This reduces them to about 7mb each with as near which makes no noticable difference.

The only issue is that as a workflow this is a bit of pain. Is there a way I can save lower size videos direct from Quicktime? I've researched saving at 720p which does very little for the file size and 480p which gives me an iphone sized video which is too small to use.

Comment: Export your Quicktime video using the Share option to compress it

Comment: Thanks, but when I go to `file > share` the options are all external sites and services, is there a way to compress the files and have the compressed version saved back to my local machine ?

Comment: Once you have done your recording you can go to File > Export and you get a choice of 1080p, 720p, 480p etc and you can same this to your Mac's harddrive or wherever you want to.

Comment: If this file is still to large, for my 24sec test I had a 13mb file from just saving it, but when I exported to 720p it went down to 8mb, if I wanted this smaller I would send it through something like Handbrake for a better compression

Comment: Thanks adam, thats what ive already been doing `export at 1080 then handbrake` which roughly gets a 20mb file down to 3-6mb, but it terms of a workflow theres allot of steps as during a testing / debugging session i could be making 20 short screen casts, i could queue them in handbrake, but id still have to manulally add each one to the queue so it dosnt save much time

Comment: OK, I see the issue, there are apps out there that can have a "Watch Folder" setup which will process video files saved into the folder, most are paid for like Sorensen Squeeze, Adobe Media Encoder, I did a quick search and there are setups using Apple scripts and automator actions using Apple Compressor. I have never tried this but I would be interested into getting this working as I could do with this type of process. I will look into this a bit more tomorrow and see what I can find.

Comment: What video and audio formats, and what container format, are your files that you want to re-encode?